# The long-running-script message in Internet Explorer

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer

After I added a WordPress function code in a comment in WordPress, the long-running-script error message is displayed in IE 11.

Other posts or pages *do not* display this error, but only the effected post does (even though I deleted the WordPress function code.)

Any workaround on this issue?

Thanks for your help.

ADDED:
The wordpress function is a simple one which enqueues a js file:

```
function iconicchild_scripts() {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'wpb_loadmore', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/datepicker.js', array('jquery'), '20150435', true );
 }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'iconicchild_scripts' );
```

As I said, I deleted it form the comment section.

Comment: well, maybe if you explained what this "a wordpress function code" actually is...

Comment: @Marc. Thanks for your comment. I modified my question to add the code.